# Swashbuckle ISchemaFilter Array of Example Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Swashbuckle 5.0.0rc-4

I am trying to setup an example request for one of my API endpoints. The default appearance Swagger shows is like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "string"
  }
]
```

This is technically correct and works when you replace the "string" with an actual value. However I want to be able to setup an example which will dispay the following:

```
[
  {
    "name": "David"
  },
  {
    "name": "John"
  },
]
```

I have tried the following but the result ended up wrapped in an extra array tag:

```
public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        schema.Type = "array";

        var examples = new OpenApiArray() {
            new OpenApiObject
            {
                ["Name"] = new OpenApiString("David")
            },
            new OpenApiObject
            {
                ["Name"] = new OpenApiString("John")
            }
        };

        schema.Example = examples;
    }
```

This however results in:

```
  [
    [ <- This isn't wanted
      {
        "name": "David"
      },
      {
        "name": "John"
      },
    ]
  ]
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. Most of the documentation I can find either doesn't mention this use case or does so by modifying xml files I'd pefer not to do.

Comment: Are you sure the correct `schema` is passed into `Apply`?

Comment: Could you share your model and Startup.cs?I could get the correct example by using your code.